# When to Use Parentheses vs. Not in Nested Function Return

Tags: swift, function, nested-function

Very new to Swift. I am really confused as to when you add `( )` and when you do not when returning a return from a nested function. An example is the code below. I know that a nested function is probably not needed, but just as an example:

```
func areaOfTriangle (width: Double, height: Double) -> Double {
    func divided () -> Double {
        return (width * height) / 2
    }
    return divided()
}
```

In `return divided()` portion, I seem to recall somewhere in my learnings that sometimes the `( )` is not needed. Can someone provide some logic as to why the parentheses is needed in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses in a *function call* are not needed if the function:

- Takes only one parameter
- The parameter itself is a function

For example the function `func funcWithHandler(handler: () -> Void) {}` can be called like this: `funcWithHandler { print("my handler executed") }`

Answer (score 0):

Use `()` when you want to execute the function.

```
return divided()
```

returns the result of the `divided`, which is a `Double`.

```
return divided
```

returns a *function* which returns a `Double` when executed.

Answer (score 0):

This line returns the value of a function call;

```
return divided()
```

This line returns the value of a "divided" variable. This variable may also refer to a function (not the value, the function itself);

```
return divided
```